# как воспользоваться сертификатами от проекта let's encrypt?

Tags: apache, nginx, ssl, сертификат, letsencrypt

с [3 декабря 2015 года](https://letsencrypt.org/2015/11/12/public-beta-timing.html) проект [let's encrypt](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Let%27s_Encrypt) перешёл в режим "public beta".

как воспользоваться сертификатами, выдаваемыми этим проектом?

Comment: [Пошаговая инструкция](http://habrahabr.ru/post/270273/) на Хабре

Comment: @Sergiks, спасибо, добавил в ответ ссылку.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

можно воспользоваться любой из [реализаций клиентов, работающих с системой let's encrypt](https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/list-of-client-implementations).

например, есть [пошаговая инструкция](http://habrahabr.ru/post/270273/) для официального клиента.

---

но мне понравился минималистичный shell-скрипт из репозитория [lukas2511](https://github.com/lukas2511/letsencrypt.sh.git), который не требует ни повышенных привилегий для своей работы, ни установки дополнительных программ/пакетов (всё необходимое обычно уже имеется в любой «серверной» установке: bash, openssl, curl и утилиты из coreutils).

### как я настроил этот клиент

1. для пущей безопасности я создал пользователя *letsencrypt* (без пароля):

   ```
   $ sudo adduser --disabled-password letsencrypt
   ```
2. открыл сеанс оболочки от имени этого пользователя:

   ```
   $ sudo -u letsencrypt -i
   letsencrypt@host:~$
   ```
3. склонировал репозиторий со скриптом и «перешёл» в созданный каталог:

   ```
   $ git clone https://github.com/lukas2511/letsencrypt.sh.git
   $ cd letsencrypt.sh
   ```

   если git не установлен, можно скачать [архив с файлами](https://github.com/lukas2511/letsencrypt.sh/archive/master.zip) и распаковать.
4. скопировал образцовый конфиг:

   ```
   $ cp config.sh.example config.sh
   ```
5. создал файл `domains.txt` для домена (мне требуется, чтобы в сертификате были имена и с `www` и без):

   ```
   domain.tld www.domain.tld
   ```

   если требуются на этой же машине и сертификаты для других доменов, то можно добавить ещё строк в этот файл, по строке для каждого сертификата.
6. создал каталог для [аутентификации](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Let%27s_Encrypt#.D0.9F.D1.80.D0.BE.D1.82.D0.BE.D0.BA.D0.BE.D0.BB_.D0.B0.D1.83.D1.82.D0.B5.D0.BD.D1.82.D0.B8.D1.84.D0.B8.D0.BA.D0.B0.D1.86.D0.B8.D0.B8_.D1.81.D0.B0.D0.B9.D1.82.D0.BE.D0.B2):

   ```
   $ mkdir .acme-challenges
   ```
7. теперь на время надо вернуться к настройкам *http-сервера*. можно завершить сеанс пользователя *letsencrypt*, а лучше открыть другое окно с оболочкой более привилегированного пользователя.

   в настройках *http-сервера* надо прописать *alias* для `/.well-known/acme-challenge`, чтобы он указывал на созданный в предыдущем пункте каталог. ориентировочно это будет `/home/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.sh/.acme-challenges`.

   1. для *nginx* в секцию `server` надо добавить `location`:

      ```
      location /.well-known/acme-challenge {
        alias /home/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.sh/.acme-challenges;
      }
      ```
   2. для *apache* в секцию `virtualhost` надо добавить строку:

      ```
      alias /.well-known/acme-challenge /home/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.sh/.acme-challenges
      ```

   это надо проделать для всех доменов (точнее, отдельных строк в созданном вами файле `domains.txt`).

   *http-сервер* после этого надо перезапустить.
8. теперь можно запускать скрипт для генерации сертификата(-ов). вернитесь к окну, где открыта оболочка, запущенная от имени пользователя *letsencrypt* (или запустите новую и перейдите в каталог со скриптом):

   ```
   $ ./letsencrypt.sh -c
   ```

   если всё пойдёт нормально, последней строкой выдачи будет:

   ```
    + Done!
   ```
9. сертификат и ключ для домена сгенерированы и лежат в каталоге `/home/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.sh/certs/domain.tld`:

   ```
   cert.pem
   privkey.pem
   ```

   в принципе, это symlink-и на актуальные версии этих файлов, которые лежат в том же каталоге и в названии которых присутствует метка времени. типа `cert-1453143084.pem`.
10. теперь можно прописывать эти файлы в настройках *http-сервера*:

    - файл с сертификатом: `/home/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.sh/certs/domain.tld/cert.pem`
    - файл с ключом: `/home/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.sh/certs/domain.tld/privkey.pem`
11. обновление сертификатов производится точно так же, как и генерация: от имени пользователя *letsencrypt* перейдите в каталог со скриптом и запустите скрипт с тем же самым параметром — `./letsencrypt.sh -c`.

    можно создать соответствующую cron-задачу, которая через пару месяцев (сертификаты генерируются на 90 дней) выполнит скрипт (от имени этого пользователя и в нужном каталоге) и перезапустит *http-сервер*.

Answer (score 0):

Центр сертификации Let's Encrypt использует протокол [Automated Certificate Management Environment](https://github.com/letsencrypt/acme-spec). Получать сертификат лучше с помощью одного из [рекомендованных клиентов](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/client-options/).
Моим выбором стал [GetSSL](https://github.com/srvrco/getssl). Это простой bash скрипт, который умеет сам себя обновлять. При работе использует CLI openssl, и значит нет жесткой привязки к версии.

GetSSL автоматизирует процесс получения и продления сертификата с помощью нескольких команд. Например, чтобы получить сертификат для домена domain.tld:

```
srv ~ # getssl -c domain.tld
creating main config file /root/.getssl/getssl.cfg
Making domain directory - /root/.getssl/domain.tld
creating domain config file in /root/.getssl/domain.tld/getssl.cfg
srv ~ # getssl domain.tld
```

Первая команда добавляет домен в список для получения (выполняется единожды), вторая - для получения сертификата.

В этой статье можно подробнее узнать о процессе [получения сертификата с помощью GetSSL](https://www.influunt.ru/getting-started-with-lets-encrypt).