# mongodb с полным использованием SSL/TLS

Tags: mongodb, ssl, tls

При попытке подключения консольным клиентом с ключом выдаёт ошибку:

> "SSL peer certificate validation failed:unsupported certificate
>   purpose"

которая не особо разгугливается из-за похожих ошибок в других продуктах.

**Обновление**

Сертификаты все сгенерированы своей CA, которая и используется везде в качестве sslCAFile, я так понял руководства от Mongo. Генерил с помощью набора скриптов easyrsa, меняя OU & CN в зависимости от назначения сертификатов.

Если такие сертификаты не подходят - в этом и есть мой вопрос - как правильно их генерить, имея свою собственную CA. Ссылку изучу, спасибо!

Comment: добро пожаловать на [ru.so]! сформулируйте, пожалуйста, сам **вопрос** (что делали, какой код написали, какую ошибку получили, без излишней информации и просьб). внести изменения можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса.

Comment: очень похоже на проблему в сертификате. обратите внимание на [этот вопрос](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23304139/4827341). откуда взят сертификат?

Comment: надеюсь, вы в курсе, что при использовании «стороннего» ca, необходимо добиться того, чтобы клиент рассматривал этот ca в качестве доверенного. чтобы отсечь возможные здесь «подводные камни», а так же получить заведомо валидный сертификат (без ошибок в purpose), предлагаю протестировать вашу систему с помощью полнценного бесплатного сертификата, например, от [*letsencrypt*](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/484031/178576) или от startssl.com.

Comment: Хорошо, я понял, видимо дело именно в этом.