# Как сделать, что бы при размещении сайта, сайт открывался firefox'ом? (перенаправление с http на https)

Tags: http, firefox, https

Закинул сайт на хостинг. Всех браузерах зайти на сайт могу. Firefox же меняет протокол http на https. Вследствие этого сайт не открывается, а отображается следующее *"Your connection is not secure. The owner of ******* has configured their website improperly. To protect your information from being stolen, Firefox has not connected to this website."*

Стоимость получения сертификата (+перехода на статический IP) велика (это виртуальный хостинг).

Как сделать, что бы любой пользователь с браузером firefox мог заходить на сайт, не отключая соответствующим способом в firefox автоматическое изменение http на https или не добавляя в исключения? Просто я, например, как пользователь, не связывался бы с таким сайтом, который требует от меня таких действий.

И вообще, может быть это сделать должен хостинг-провайдер? Т.е. он возможно должен получить сертификат для себя, и обеспечивать доступ по https для всех клиентов? С другой стороны регистратор (и хостинг-провайдер) барыжит сертификатами

Comment: кэш браузера чистили? просто для справки: абсолютно бесплатно можно получить сертификат, например, на startssl.com и на [letsencrypt.org](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/484031/178576])

Comment: Я знаю где получить бесплатные сертификаты, но это виртуальных хостинг. Тут не дают пароль, соответственно ничего нельзя поставить

Comment: Firefox просто так ничего не меняет. Вероятно, установлен плагин-перенаправитель с http на https.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Какой-то косяк в Firefox моей Ubuntu, потому что в Windows все работает

Answer (score 0):

Плагин в Firefox стоит, который при возможности использовать https, принудительно использует безопасное подключение. У себя можно отключить, а у других посетителей как? В некоторых сборках на Chromium, такое же поведение по-умолчанию. Надо настройки хостинга смотреть, обычно там галка стоит "Сайт доступен по https" и самоподписной сертификат используется.