# Требования к shared хостингу для SSL сертификата Let’sEncrypt

Tags: apache, nginx, ssl, letsencrypt

Есть желание установить SSL сертификат Let’sEncrypt на обычный хостинг, но не могу понять, какие минимальные требования у этого хостинга должны быть помимо SSH.

Comment: Минимальных требований никаких (в том числе ssh незачем), лишь бы хостинг позволял свой сертификат поставить

Comment: А как генерить сертификат без SSH если он генерится на сервере где его и устанавливают?

Comment: На любом другом доступном компьютере, на сервере требуется лишь создать файлик для проверки

Comment: https://certbot.eff.org/docs/using.html#manual

Comment: @ДмитрийГвоздь сертификат генерируется на стороне Let’sEncrypt. Я настраивал на simplecloud. Делал по инструкции. Проблем не было.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman вот этого точно делать не стоит

Comment: @PavelMayorov чего именно?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman доверять все этапы генерации третьей стороне

Comment: @PavelMayorov сам сертификат генерируется всегда сертифицирующим органом. про ключи и запросы речь не идет.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman а автору вопроса SSH именно для генерации ключей и потребовался.

Comment: @PavelMayorov я ведь ничего не писал про SSH. я написал комментарий на вот эту фразу _Кто пытался решить данный вопрос, поделитесь информацией_

Comment: @MikhailVaysman вы отвечали на вот это сообщение: *"А как генерить сертификат без SSH если он генерится на сервере где его и устанавливают?"* Очевидно, тут имелась в виду генерация ключей и запроса.

Comment: @PavelMayorov некоторые хостеры поддерживают генерацию сертификатов автоматически, то есть нужды в SSH нет.

Comment: @PavelMayorov там есть функционал предоставления своих csr для тех, кто этого хочет

Answer (score 0):

> минимальные требования у этого хостинга должны быть помимо SSH.

для скрипта от [lukas2511](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/484032/178576) — весьма скромные: bash, openssl, curl, diff и утилиты из coreutils.

да, естественно, должна быть возможность подправить конфигурацию http-сервера.

---

а вообще вопрос слишком общий — [клиентов написано вагон и маленькая тележка](https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/list-of-client-implementations/2103). и у каждого список требуемых программ может быть свой уникальный.