# Получение сертификатов на несколько поддоменов nginx django

Tags: nginx, ssl, letsencrypt

Стоит задача сгенерить несколько поддоменов, на каждый из них нужен сертификат.

В базе данных хранятся названия, исходя из которых это нужно сделать, и все они (названия) в кирилице. Пусть будет блог, новости и так далее. Поддоменов много, по этому руками это делать не комильфо.

Предполагаю, что нужен `bash` скрипт, который заменит `DOMAIN_NAME` в `nginx` конфиге.
Примерно так:

```
sed -i "s/my.example.com/$DOMAIN_NAME/g" /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

Но при этом нужно название перевести в punycode, пока не понимаю как это верно сделать.

И сразу же встаёт вопрос:

Нужен ли отдельный `nginx` конфиг под каждый поддомен. Конфиг один от другого не будет отличаться ничем, кроме `server_name`, `ssl_certificate`, `ssl_certificate_key`
Если нет, то нужно ещё и генерить по конфигу, что не хотелось бы.

Далее, нужно сгенерить сертификат, я это делал при помощи `letsencrypt-auto certonly --standalone)`, но в этом случае, приходилось тормозить `nginx`, т.к. standalone требует свободных 443 и 80 портов.

Если не тормозить, то нужно юзать `letsencrypt-auto certonly --webroot` или я не правильно понимаю [документацию](http://letsencrypt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using.html) ?

В общем, задача не кажется очень простой. Скрипт нужно писать и проверять на правильность выполнения, при том учёте, что использовать его нужно всего один раз.

Возможно кто-то уже решал подобную задачу и имеет какое-то решение, или по крайней мере подскажет, как сделать более элегантно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> нужно название перевести в punycode

можно воспользоваться, например, программой [idn](https://www.gnu.org/software/libidn/manual/libidn.html#Invoking-idn) (имеется в репозиториях всех популярных дистрибутивов):

```
$ idn домен.рф под.домен.org
xn--d1acufc.xn--p1ai
xn--d1atc.xn--d1acufc.org
```

> Нужен ли отдельный nginx конфиг под каждый поддомен

насколько я знаю, [ситуация с 2013 года](https://serverfault.com/q/505015/292034) не изменилась, и использовать переменные типа `$server_name` в директивах типа `ssl_certificate` невозможно: надо создавать отдельные секции `server` под каждый [под]домен (в одном файле или в нескольких — не имеет значения).

> Конфиг один от другого не будет отличаться ничем, кроме `server_name`, `ssl_certificate`, `ssl_certificate_key`

общую часть секции `server` можно вынести в отдельный файл и подключать [директивой include](http://nginx.org/ru/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include) (если путь не абсолютный, то он «отсчитывается» от каталога, в котором находится «глобальный» [конф.файл](https://nginx.ru/ru/docs/beginners_guide.html)).

> Далее, нужно сгенерить сертификат, я это делал при помощи `letsencrypt-auto certonly --standalone`, но в этом случае, приходилось тормозить nginx, т.к. standalone требует свободных 443 и 80 портов

вообще для «обратного звонка» серверы *letsencrypt-а* используют только 80-й порт (что более чем логично — ведь сертификат-то в этот момент ещё не выдан) и «стучатся» по адресу `http://ваш.домен/.well-known/acme-challenge/файл-который-создаёт-клиент-letsencrypt-а`. т.е., нужна секция секция `location` внутри секции `server`, слуающей 80-й порт, примерно такого вида (она, кстати, универсальна, и можно также подключать её из общего для всех доменов файла директивой `include`):

```
location /.well-known/acme-challenge {
  alias /путь/к/каталогу/где/клиент/letsencrypt/будет/создавать/проверочные/файлы;
}
```

можете глянуть на [седьмой пункт моей инструкции](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/484032/178576) по использованию одного из множества клиентов (сама инструкция чуть устарела — автор переименовал клиента, но ссылка на проект рабочая — github перебрасывает на новое имя — [dehydrated](https://github.com/lukas2511/dehydrated))

> Скрипт нужно писать и проверять на правильность выполнения, при том учёте, что использовать его нужно всего один раз.

если один раз — так незачем писать. просто сгенерируйте нужный конфигурационный файл, да и всё.

типа:

```
$ echo 'select поле-с-именем-домена from таблица' | mysql -N > список.доменов
$ cat список.доменов | idn > список.в.кодировке.inda
$ cat список.в.кодировке.inda | while read d; do \
echo -e "server {\n server_name \"$d\";\n include файл;\n \
ssl_certificate \"/путь/к/$d.crt\";\n \
ssl_certificate_key \"/путь/к/$d.key\";\n}\n\n"; \
done > файл.с.секциями.server
```

можно и вообще однострочник сделать, если убрать сохранение промежуточных файлов, и связать команды конвейерами `|`.